# Sed Command modification to make it work

Tags: bash, shell

In sed I just want to replace a range of text to a blank space from 13 to 21 line number and print rest all the line as it is. Please help me out.

Comment: it would help if you can add sample input file with expected output... see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete lines 13 through 21

```
sed -i '13,21d' file
```

That will remove the lines from the file, if you don't want to actually delete them, but just remove them from your output

```
sed -e '13,21d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

to replace content lines with blanks

```
$ sed '13,21s/.*//' file
```